# How to disable angular input field by using mat-slide-toggle?

Tags: angularjs, html, typescript

How to disable angular mat-form-field(input) field using [mat-slide-toggle](https://material.angular.io/components/slide-toggle/overview) in reactive forms, when slide toggle on input field is true it should be enabled otherwise input 
field should be disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `change` method on `mat-slide-toggle` as

```
    <mat-slide-toggle 
      (change)="changeDisable()" formControlName="enableWifi">
      Enable Wifi</mat-slide-toggle>
<mat-form-field class="demo-full-width">  
        <input [disabled]="checked" formControlName="FirstName" matInput
         placeholder="First Name">  
 </mat-form-field> 

changeDisable() {
  if (this.formGroup.controls['FirstName'].disabled) {
   this.formGroup.controls['FirstName'].enable() ;
  } else {
    this.formGroup.controls['FirstName'].disable() ;
  }

}
```

**[Stackblitz Demo showing Input Disable/Enable on Change of mat toggle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-slide-toggle-example-ddwtsf?file=app/slide-toggle-overview-example.html)**

Comment: Hello sir, your example is good but i want input field disabled when slide off and enabled when slide on.how can achieve this .plz help me.

Comment: @gausshaikh add `this.formGroup.controls['FirstName'].disable();` line in `ngOnInit` to make input disable at start-up. See, the link now, its updated

Comment: Thank You Sir,You are Great.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

in html:

```
<mat-slide-toggle (change)="toggle($event)">Slide me!</mat-slide-toggle>
<input [attr.disabled]="show ? '' : null"/>{{show}}
```

in ts:

```
    show: boolean = false;
    toggle(e: any) {
      e.checked? this.show = true: this.show = false;
    }
```

Comment: i want disabled not hide.

Comment: not working sir, i found solution, but it is delay, i want input field disabled onLoad.

Comment: "this.show = e.checked" is a better way anyway